# phalcon official website demo The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, phalcon

phalcon official website demo
"Exception:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

[image]

[image]

I can't get answer from Google or other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
ALTER USER ‘root’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘root’;
```

It's ok~